# Filter AJAX response with String or DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string, dom

I'm getting am AJAX response and need to trim it down to include only the elements I want. From what I know I have two main options. First option would be to manipulate the response as a string, using `substring`, `split`, and other string methods then append a single time. The other option would be to append to a dummy element and manipulate from there using jQuery methods.

DOM manipulations are expensive and slow down my loading time. String manipulations are a pain in the ass to code, feel increasingly "hacky", and can become almost illegible. To me, both suck. What do you recommend I use and/or could you suggest a different approach?

**UPDATE:**

The response comes in as a string from an RSS feed and I can't do anything on the server side.

Comment: use option 2 with a detached dom node as to not cause unwanted redraws. `var thehtml = $("<div>").html(myhtml);` now manipulate `thehtml`

Comment: Are you restricted from modifying the raw response on the server side? You can do url:'page.php#someID' and it will fetch the html of that ID

Comment: you can filter your ajax request to just get certain parts of the HTML as a response. So you would do `$.get('/your_url #filtered_content', data, complete_callback_func);` See http://api.jquery.com/load/ for details

Comment: @KevinB should I use `thehtml.getElementById("foo");` since it's not in the `document`, `document.getElementById("foo");` wouldn't work?

Comment: No, use jQuery. `thehtml.find("#foo")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second one, but don't touch the DOM until you have what you want.  The JQuery function can accept arbitrary HTML and will construct the DOM nodes in it, after which you can do all the filtering you want, then append:

```
var $nodes = $("<div class='a'>1</div><div class='b'>2</div>");
$('#a_stuff').append($nodes.filter('div.a'));
$('#b_stuff').append($nodes.filter('div.b'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter your ajax request to just get certain parts of the HTML as a response. So you would do `$.get('/your_url #filtered_content', data, complete_callback_func);` See http://api.jquery.com/load/ for details

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use $(responseString) which returns a jQuery object that you can manipulate like a normal dom object.

Example

```
var ajaxResponse = '<div class="outer"><span class="inner">Some text</span></div>';
var obj = $(ajaxResponse );
```

Now you can append the .inner span to the body like this

```
obj.children('.inner').appendTo('body');
```